# Type superscripts of multiple characters to express mathematical exponents

Tags: unicode, special-characters, control-characters

If in linux I type `CTRL-shift-U`, followed by a unicode control code, I can type a superscript.

So if I type `10`, followed by `CTRL-shift-U`, followed by `b9`, I can get `10¹`.

How though do I write something like 10 to the power of 18?

Answer (score 1):

Install `gucharmap`, the GNOME Character Map tool, and find the codepoint number in there. It is always shown as "U+xxxx" (four or more digits).

The codepoint for "superscript 8" is U+**2078**, from the [Superscripts and Subscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts_(Unicode_block)) Unicode block. Most superscript digits correspond to U+207x in this block, with the exception of 123 (which are U+00B9, U+00B2, and U+00B3 respectively).

(The reason is that ¹²³ were originally imported from another codepage where they already existed, so they were placed in one of the initial blocks, but all other subscript and superscript numerals were added "fresh" to Unicode so they got their own block. For example, IBM codepage 437 had ² long before Unicode.)

---

An alternative method is to repurpose one of the keyboard's keys as the [Compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts_(Unicode_block)) key. (For example, if your Caps Lock is entirely unused, you could remap it to Compose.) Afterwards, pressing <kbd>Compose</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> and <kbd>6</kbd> would give you ⁶.

Comment: So you type each control code in turn to print each superscript char in succession? When I tried this, I got little spaces between each char, making them look not quite like an exponent of 18, for example, but like 1 8. But now I find if I paste them here, they appear without such spaing, thus: 10¹²³. So it my problem is my use of a monospace font, which puts big gaps between each of them and makes it seem like I need to use some other control code to get multi-char exponents.

Comment: Yes, that's literally what "monospace font" means: _each_ character, without exception, has the same width. (This also applies to superscripts because they're _not really_ superscripts as far as the text layout code cares – they still have the same font size as main text, the same baseline as main text, so they also occupy the same amount of space in a monospace font.)

Comment: There is no such thing as "multi-char exponents" in Unicode in general. (IMHO, it's _almost_ out-of-scope for Unicode – certainly not impossible in theory, considering it already has "[fraction slash](https://superuser.com/q/922074/1686)", but not really the _job_ of Unicode.) To get nice-looking exponents you need to write the document in a format that supports real superscripts, such as `10<sup>18</sup>` in HTML (or math features in MS Word or LaTeX) – as that's a layout feature it _can_ just take regular digits and shrink them to superscript size, even in monospace fonts.